# YAML enum parser issue in Swagger Editor

Tags: yaml, swagger-editor

When converting following JSON enum to YAML in the SmartBear Swagger Editor, value '0008' and '0009' of the enumeration of String type are no longer considered as a string but become a numeric value:

Swagger Editor : https://editor.swagger.io/
OS : Windows 10
Browsers : Edge and Google Chrome

JSON format:

```
"CardStatusCode": {
  "pattern": "^[0-9]{1,4}$",
  "type": "string",
  "enum": [
    "0000",
    "0001",
    "0002",
    "0003",
    "0004",
    "0005",
    "0006",
    "0007",
    "0008",
    "0009"
  ],
  "example": "0002"
}
```

"Convert to YAML" format:

CardStatusCode:
pattern: '^[0-9]{1,4}$'
type: string
enum:
- '0000'
- '0001'
- '0002'
- '0003'
- '0004'
- '0005'
- '0006'
- '0007'
- 0008
- 0009
example: '0002'

Is this a bug in the YAML parser?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in https://editor.swagger.io. When I paste `{"enum": ["0001","0002","0003","0004"]}` into the editor, the 4th value remains a string - `'0004'`. Do you use the online editor or a locally installed version? What is your browser and OS?

Comment: The JSON and YAML content you give are nothing alike: JSON has three times `"0001"`, the `description` in JSON is very different from the one in YAML. Please ensure that you show us your actual input and output.